# post data in angular2

Tags: json, angular

I am facing the issue of json added being added to the url after calling the service to add the data.

below is my file

first.ts

```
CreateNew(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['/detail', 0]);
}
```

detail.ts

```
Submit() {
    let templateId;
    this.route.params.subscribe(
        (param: any) => {
            templateId = +param['templateid']; });
    if (templateId === 0) {
        this.jobservice.addJob(this.job).subscribe(error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/template']);
}
```

service.ts

```
addJob(job: Job): Observable <Job> {

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log(job);
    return this.http.post('http://sample/api/Product/AddProduct', JSON.stringify(job), options).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I am not able to find the issue why it is adding the json data to the url.

Comment: What is the URL ?

Comment: It is adding the data to of the json e.g. if url is http://localhost:51293/template it is adding like below http://localhost:51293/template?templateid=0&templatename=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that while refresh of page it was showing 404 error.
In app.module.ts

Add imports: import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
And in NgMoudle provider, add: {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the RequestOption, you dont use the method post, get, put or delete. But you use "request". Here is a sample request that works:

```
 post<RQ, RS>(url: string, request: RQ, responseType: RS, withToken: boolean): Promise<RS> {
        let postReq: Request = this.createAuthorizationHeader<RQ>(url, request, RequestMethod.Post, withToken);
        return this.http.request(postReq).toPromise()
            .then(res => {
                return this.processingData<RS>(res, responseType);
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Then here you add your header to the request:

```
/**
 * This function updates the token in the header
 */
createAuthorizationHeader<RQ>(url: string, requestData: RQ, method: RequestMethod, withToken: boolean) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    let options = new RequestOptions({
        method: method,
        url: url
    });
    /**
     * Include token when boolean is passed
     */
    if (withToken) {
        headers.append('token', token);
        options.headers = headers;
    }
    /**
     * create bosy for post and put
     */
    if (method === RequestMethod.Post || method === RequestMethod.Put) {
        // do something
    }
    let request = new Request(options);
    return request;
}
```

This should work, remember to use "http.request.." when you use request options

```
import { Http, Request, Response, Headers, RequestMethod, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
...
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({
    method: RequestMethod.Post,
    url: url,
    headers = headers,
    body: job
});
let request = new Request(options);
console.log(options);
return this.http.request(options).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: I have tried but issue still exists. The url becomes something like this localhost:51293/template?templateid=0&templatename=  and shows error 404.

Answer (score 0):

This should be working out fine. I have this working on my environment using angular 2.1.0.

```
import { Http, Request, Response, Headers, RequestMethod, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
...
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({
    method: RequestMethod.Post,
    url: 'localhost:51293/template',
    headers = headers,
    body: job
});
let request = new Request(options);
console.log(options);
return this.http.request(options).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
```